# What prevents the electron in electron field from dissipating into the surrounding electron quantum field?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, electrons

As I understand quantum field theory, electrons are excitations in the electron field.

So if these are vibrations in the electron field then what prevents an electron from loosing its energy (of vibration) into the surrounding?

Comment: It really doesn't sound like you understand quantum field theory at all. How about giving a QFT intro a go? Your question doesn't make a lot of sense, and I think you will see that yourself if you do give it a go.

Comment: Yeah  but still how can vibration in a field prevent itself from dissipating into the surrounding?

Comment: Energy dissipation is normally a macroscopic phenomenon being caused by microscopic processes (i.e. colliding particles). In the microscopic/elementary picture of QFT there can't be just energy dissipation by itself, but interactions between fields. These interactions follow certain symmetries/conservation laws. For example there is charge conservation which makes it impossible for an electron to just vanish. However the electron (-field) could interact with a positron (it's anti-particle) and "dissipate" their energy in the form of photons.

Comment: *Nothing prevents it*. It happens all the time. An electron in a given state couples via photons to all kinds of things and loses or gains energy all the time. The theory is called QED. An electron in a CRT tube will lose most of its energy at its death-event interaction on the screen.